# How to debug my Node.js TypeScript project in Chrome dev tools

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I am trying to add a debug script in my `package.json` file. For a plain Node project this code works:

```
"debug": "node --inspect index.js"
```

And for Node TypeScript project I did this:

```
"debug": "ts-node --inspect --require ts-node/register index.ts"
```

But this gives me error:

```
Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --inspect
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to pass the `--inspect` option directly to node as indicated in [this ts-node issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/218).

```
node <node options here> --require ts-node/register
```

or

```
node <node options here> --loader ts-node/esm
```

So for your example, it would be

```
 "debug": "node --inspect --require ts-node/register index.ts"
```